# Connect to an external Database (other Host) on Drupal 7

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7, migrate

I want to connect to an external Database on another Host (not localhost) on Drupal because i want to migrate Content with the Migrate Module.

thats in my settings.php

```
$databases['for_migration']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'dbname',
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'password',
  'host' => 'other-host.com',
  'prefix' => '',
  'port' => '',
);
```

And in another method im calling the database via:

```
$query = Database::getConnection('default', 'for_migration')
```

thats the error which appears:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'host.com' (13) in    MigrateMigration->__construct() (Zeile 16 von /var/www/html/x/sites/all/modules/migrate_x/x.inc).
```

So if i call a database on localhost, there are no errors and all migrates perfectly. But i cant connect to a database on an external host.

Comment: Probably MySQL on other-host doesn't allow external connections

Comment: Where can I look for this configuration?

Comment: If host.com runs a Debian-based Linux distro, it'll be in /etc/mysql/my.cnf.

Comment: its CentOS, but in the my.cnf is no entry for something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my fault. I have set httpd_can_network_connect on the remote server to on.

But the solution was to set it on my local machine. After that i can connect to an external Host. So it was a SELinux Problem.

Thanks to @fobia

Answer (score 1):

That could be due to:
1) connection limitation (firewall block, for example).
2) the account you are using does not allows logins outside of "localhost". In this case, you will have to edit your account hostname mask on the 'user' table inside the 'mysql' database for '%' (which means, any address) or the machine IP address you are accessing from.

Comment: In the mysql-database -> user-table, and for that account host = % ?

Comment: yea, that will do it. just keep in my that allowing connections from "anywhere" is not safe. :) you can read more about access control here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connection-access.html

Comment: i have changed the value from 'localhost' to '%', restarted mysqld,  but its still not connecting.

Comment: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'myIPadress' (13) in MigrateSpeNaeMigration->__construct() (Zeile 16 von /var/www/html/spe/sites/all/modules/migrate_spe/importSPE.inc).

Comment: I made some research, and I have found that one of the recommendations for situations such as the one you are having is to execute the following command to enable network connection over HTTPD:

setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1

Comment: so thats the output for these settings:'[DBA@localhost spe]$ sestatus -b | grep httpd_can_network
httpd_can_network_connect                   off
httpd_can_network_connect_cobbler           off
httpd_can_network_connect_db                off
httpd_can_network_memcache                  off
httpd_can_network_relay                     off'
So i will try with httpd_can_network_connect and httpd_can_network_connect_db

Comment: i have turned on httpd_can_network_connect_db and httpd_can_network_connect but nothing happens :(

Comment: Can you confirm that the login you are using on the server you are trying to connect to has the following configuration at the mysql user table:
`code`
  host | username      | password  | ...
  %    | your_username | xxxxxxx   | ...
`code`

Comment: yea host | user | password, thats right. and the value in 'host' is '%'